# Rails remote: true undefined method in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a Rails 5.0.2 app and I've managed to implement a user following system using the `acts_as_follower` gem. Everything works nicely, however, I'm running into some trouble adding ajax.

I'm getting the following error when clicking 'follow'

```
NoMethodError at /7/follow
==========================

> undefined method `followed_by?' for nil:NilClass
```

I have the following

`users_controller.rb`

```
def follow
  user = User.find(params[:id])
  current_user.follow(user)

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to user}
    format.js
  end
end
```

`show.html.erb`

```
...
<div id="follow">
  <%= render partial: "users/following", locals: {user: @user} %>
</div>
...
```

`_following.html.erb`

```
<% if !@user.followed_by?(current_user) %>
  <%= link_to follow_user_path(@user.id), remote: true do %>
    <h4><span class="label label-primary">Follow</span></h4>
  <% end %>
<% else %>
  <%= link_to unfollow_user_path(@user.id) do %>
    <h4><span class="label label-primary">Unfollow</span></h4>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I understand that I have no `@user` in my partial after creating the record and I can't work out how to pass it back in to the partial. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Silly me.

In the follow method I had this:

```
def follow
  user = User.find(params[:id])
  current_user.follow(user)

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to user}
    format.js
  end
end
```

but should have been

```
def follow
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  current_user.follow(@user)

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to @user}
    format.js
  end
end
```

`@user` rather than `user`

Answer (score 0):

your problem here is that in your controller you have user, without the "@" user is a variable that exist just in your controller method, and @user is an instance variable that can be accessed on the view.

So if you plan to use this on the view, you need to add "@" to the variable.